# Bootstrap Datepicker shows up in firefox but dosent shows up in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) to change date in modal. I have looked at so many pages in bootstrap regarding the same problem. I tried almost all of them but in the end it didn't work.
Here is my code

```
<div id="create_date_picker" class="input-group input-group-lg input-append date">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start_date" readonly placeholder="Start Date">
   <span class="input-group-btn add-on">
     <a><img src="{% static 'img/icn-date.png' %}"></a>
   </span>
</div>
```

I'm calling datepicker with these lines :

```
<link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

var date_options = {
    format: 'dd/M/yyyy',
    startDate: today
};

$('#create_date_picker').datepicker(date_options);
$('#create_date_picker').datepicker('update', today);
```

What i am missing because of which date picker is not showing up only in chrome?. There is no error in console also.

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: Like i told you in your same exact question before (now deleted), your code works for me on chrome so i guess your issue comes from somewhere else. Aren't you still unable to provide any online link which reproduces your issue?

Comment: no i am unable to replicate the same issue on fiddle

Comment: @pythonbytes So maybe just a CSS issue, inspect element and check

Comment: so should i need to update css or what

Comment: You need to find what makes it buggy on chrome, you need to debug it using dev tool, nothing we can do without seeing any online sample which replicates your issue

Comment: Have you tried using $(document).ready()? That might be a reason as to why it's not displaying. Also, try typing into the console to create the datepicker manually (e.g. $("#table").datepicker();).